# Running subprocess.popen in celery task gives status code 134(SIGABRT) error

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, celery, sigabrt

I am trying to run a subprocess inside a celery task, with `subprocess.popen`, but I get `return code 134` in return as soon as it executes the command. Below is my code to run the command, where I create a subprocess and try to get the stdout of the process generated, and when/if the process ends successfully, I expect to get a `return code` of 0.

```
try:
    print("Executing command: {}".format(" ".join(args)))
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True
    )
    print("Processing Started...")
    while True:
        output = process.stdout.readline()
        print(output.strip())
        return_code = process.poll()
        if return_code is not None:
            print("RETURN CODE", return_code)
            # Process has finished, read rest of the output
            if return_code == 0:
                print("Processing Completed.")
            else:
                for output in process.stdout.readlines():
                    print(output.strip())
                print(
                    "Some Error occured during script execution. Script: {}".format(
                        " ".join(args)
                    )
                )
            break

except Exception as err:
    print("Error while excuting the script. Error: {}".format(err))
    return False
else:
    return return_code == 0
```

The command I am passing in the function is passed as an array of string(known as args), as below:

`['/home/user/metashape-pro/metashape.sh', '-r', '/home/user/app/geoprocessing-api/init_doc.py', '--project_name', 'mine_2', '--geo_projection', 'EPSG::4326', '--execution_step', '1']`

So, when I run this command outside on a console, it runs fine, but when the subprocess runs it inside a celery task, I get `RETURN CODE 134` from the output immediately, without any other error from the print statements(all outputs are read from the celery log file).

What is it that I am doing wrong, am I not passing the environment for subprocess.popen, or is there a user permission issue here to execute the command? or some other parameter of popen is missing from the above code?

Thanks

Comment: Celery uses https://github.com/celery/billiard for process-related stuff. I suggest you try using billiard instead and see if it helps.

Comment: @jbndlr any help over here. I saw your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60842801/need-to-send-response-status-code-right-away-with-fastapi-while-keeping-jobs-syn
but can't figure out my own way with it.

Comment: @DejanLekic I don't know if exploring a new multiprocessing topic will help me, plus when you go to billiards documentation, it just takes you to multiprocessing documentation and no help/info on how to use billiards(since its a fork of multiprocessing). Is there something I can do with my code, or what I am doing is completely wrong?

Comment: Billiard probably has something similar or exactly like subprocess.popen() that you should try. It should be as straightforward as changing one or two imports and changing your existing popen() call...

Comment: @DejanLekic I tried ur approach just to end up with same sigabrt error.
below is the code I used to call above run command function
`output = False
step_options = {
    "project_name": project_id,
    "geo_projection": geo_projection,
    "execution_step": 1,
}
args = get_command(step_options)
curr_step = step_options["execution_step"]
p = Process(target=run_command, args=(args,))
p.start()
# p.join()
output = p.exitcode == 0
print('output', output, p.exitcode)`

seems to me like a subprocess issue. What can I do to run the command mentioned in the question?

Comment: url of the image of code: https://imgur.com/a/MseJEI5